# Initialize Function, Adding component to container

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

here is a code sample  which should have worked but didn't

```
var rows=[];
for(var i=0; i<5;i++)
{
   rows.push(Ext.create(Prototype.view.RowModel));
}
this.add(rows);
```

It only adds one row when it should add 5.

Why? tried it with different ID for each row, still didn't make me have more than one.

[image: RowModel code]
[image: Container Code]

Comment: is the `RowModel` a view ? If yes, what does it extends ?

Comment: Row Model is a Panel which is filled with TextField and NumberField with an HBOX layout.

Added SS for you

Comment: alright, I'll try to find problem as you've posted code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it does not work with panel containers, but if I use a simple container it does. For me it's problem solved, but it would be interesing to know why it does not work with panels.